# bacula catalog backup error

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backup, bacula

I have a Bacula (mysql) server on an Ubuntu-server machine. It backs up and restore without issues except for the catalog. Every time it runs the catalog backup it shows an error. My guess is that there must be some kind of permission issues somewhere. I've read over many forums and I can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by giving execute permission to user *bacula* on /etc/bacula/scripts/delete_catalog_backup